# Changing CodeIgniter url_title from Czech characters to standard English characters

Tags: codeigniter, url, utf-8, url-rewriting, page-title

What's the best way to save CodeIgniter url_title's originally written using Czech characters as standard English characters? For example:

Currently this:
`/projects/Hledám-sponzora-na-nákup-příslušenství-k-invalidní1/123`

I'd prefer this:
`/projects/hledam-sponzora-na-nakup-prislusenstvi-k-invalidni1/123`

I tried changing just the url_title table collation to non-Czech, but it caused an error when submitting the form. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anybody needs it (a year later), try with `convert_accented_characters()` of the [Text Helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/text_helper.html). This is how I do it:

```
url_title(convert_accented_characters($title_with_accents), 'dash', TRUE)
```

Works quite well :)

You can also check the file `application/config/foreign_chars.php` and edit it if it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to do... Are these urls? If so, I'd choose numbers that associate to the titles you want to use.

Could you show the markup of the form? Also the controller function that handles the submission could be major help... Help us help you!

Comment: It seems life can go on without changing these to non-Czech characters. The original idea was to replace `á` for example with `a` in URLs. No big deal though.